# How can I properly identify Cannondale Bad Boy 1 year model?

Tags: cannondale

I'm looking to purchase a Cannondale Bad Boy 1 through Craigslist, owner not entirely sure which year model, how can I identify which year is it?

Comment: if you have access to Cannondale's back catalog, probably as easy as looking at the paint job.

Comment: i don't have access to cannondale's back catalog, is there any other way I can identify it?

Comment: any use? [www.cannondale.com/gbr/bikes/archive/](http://www.cannondale.com/gbr/bikes/archive/)

Comment: that's not really useful for me as I'm newbie myself, I guess there is no real way to quickly check it(

Comment: Why is the year that important?  If there was component or frame change then you would know from that.  Components and condition is the main thing.

Comment: All the bad boy bikes look pretty similar. I think (but am not sure) that the end of Cannondale serial numbers indicates the year (and the serial number is normally under the bottom bracket). In any case, compare the components with whats in the catalog (you can figure out what the components are by looking at the labels on them).